# Postfix relay: Forward one domain on untouched. All others, redirect

Tags: email, postfix

I'm currently using a virtual_maps config with regex to forward all emails sent to my postfix server to one email address

`/.+@.+/ email@example.com`

I'd like to make an exception to the forwarding rule for one domain. That domain should be forwarded on to AWS SES untouched.  i.e. me@example.com should be relayed on to me@example.com, but you@domain.com should be sent to email@example.com, as it does with my current configuration.

I have the relaying working fine, so the only problem is getting postfix to relay the one domain untouched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this PCRE table:

```
/^([^@]+@example\.com)$/ $1
/.+@.+/ email@example.com
```

In this scenario, if Postfix queries `me@example.com`, the first entry matches and `me@example.com` (the captured string) is returned. Or else, the second entry matches and `email@example.com` is always returned.